# Is it possible to update specific app files for Shiny app hosted on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I developed an app and deployed it privately on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/). Since deploying the app, I've partially implemented some major breaking changes. Now, I would like to update one specific data file that was deployed in version 1 of my app without deploying *all* of my current (incomplete) updates. Is this possible?

I realize that I can achieve this by carefully versioning my deployments with git, but IMO something like `rsconnect::update_app_files(app = "my-app", files = "foo.csv")` would be much easier and quicker.

Comment: Bump I want this also